# Explanation of available disk space on linux

Tags: linux, diskspace, ext3

Can you explain why the available space is only 78G but the different beetween 905G and 782 is 123?
Where is the other 45?

> /dev/md2              905G  782G   78G  92% /var

File system is EXT-3

Comment: What filesystem are you using? -> see that filesystem documentation

Comment: File system is EXT-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i check that is normal on ext-3 that filesystem reserve 5% of disk.

For free that you can do this command

> tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1